# expl3/l3keys/\keyval_parse:nn - What is the reason for order of appending <key> and <value> to <code2>?

Tags: expl3, l3keys

In interface3.pdf, released 2021-07-12, section "26.8 Low-level interface for parsing key–val lists" you find:

> `\keyval_parse:nnn` ✩  New: 2020-12-19 Updated: 2021-05-10
>
> `\keyval_parse:nnn {⟨code1⟩}{⟨code2⟩}{⟨key–value list⟩}`
>
> Parses the *⟨key–value list⟩* into a series of *⟨keys⟩* and
> associated *⟨values⟩*, or keys alone (if no ⟨value⟩ was given).
> *⟨code1⟩* receives each *⟨key⟩* (with no ⟨value⟩) as a
> trailing brace group, whereas *⟨code2⟩* is appended by two brace
> groups, the *⟨key⟩* and *⟨value⟩*. The order of the
> *⟨keys⟩* in the ⟨key–value list⟩ is preserved. ...

**I wonder why with *⟨code2⟩* the order of appending is `{⟨key⟩}{⟨value⟩}` instead of  `{⟨value⟩}{⟨key⟩}`.**

If the latter was the case, you could more easily call exactly the same function/macro both with *⟨code1⟩* and with *⟨code2⟩* and hereby with *⟨code1⟩* just provide a default for the missing value.

With the current state you can't do this - instead you need to exchange arguments in one of the two cases of a value not being provided / a value being provided:

Assume, e.g., on wishes to call a function `\__MYMODULE_foobar:nnnn` with

- its first argument being the phrase "foo",
- its second argument being the phrase "bar",
- probably its third argument being the name of the key,
- probably its fourth argument either being the tokens that form the value, or, in case of no value being provided, being the phrase "bazdefault".

Currently one needs to do something like:

```latex
\cs_new:Nn \__MYMODULE_exchange_i_iii_ii:nnn  { #1 {#3} {#2} }
\cs_new:Nn \__MYMODULE_foobar:nnnn {First~arg~is:#1.~Second~arg~is:#2.~Key~is:~#3.~Value~or~default~is:~#4.}
...
\keyval_parse:nn {  \__MYMODULE_exchange_i_iii_ii:nnn {\__MYMODULE_foobar:nnnn {foo}{bar}} {bazdefault}   }
                 {  \__MYMODULE_foobar:nnnn {foo}{bar}  }
                 {   A=B,C   }
...
```

If with *⟨code2⟩* the order of appending was `{⟨value⟩}{⟨key⟩}` instead of `{⟨key⟩}{⟨value⟩}`, then one could in the `\__MYMODULE_foobar:nnnn`-function exchange the last and the last-but-one argument and more simply do:

```latex
\cs_new:Nn \__MYMODULE_foobar:nnnn {First~arg~is:#1.~Second~arg~is:#2.~Key~is:~#4.~Value~or~default~is:~#3.}
...
\keyval_parse:nn {  \__MYMODULE_foobar:nnnn {foo}{bar}{bazdefault}   }
                 {  \__MYMODULE_foobar:nnnn {foo}{bar}  }
                 {   A=B,C   }
...
```

I would find that convenient. But I can't rule out that there are good reasons, which I just don't see, not to do it that way, but the way it is currently done.

The similarity to `\keyval_parse:NNn`, where you need to have two different functions defined anyway, would be smaller. But also here one might have swapped the order of the two arguments of *⟨function2⟩*.

Comment: 'Why' questions are hard, and I didn't write the code in question, but I'd say: 1) As it's like `\keyval_parse:NNn`; 2) Because it's `key=value` not `value=key`; and 3) Because keys with and without values should be treated independently in general terms.

Comment: As I wrote the code I can answer the original why: Backwards compatibility for `\keyval_parse:NNn` (since `\keyval_parse:nnn` replaces it internally, `\keyval_parse:NNn` is just let to it now). Also having `\keyval_parse:NNn` and `\keyval_parse:nnn` return the arguments in a different order is bound to lead to confusion. (For me the first argument was the binding one)